# How to prevent uploading image or file having executable code in php or using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, web-config

I want to check whether the image or file is executable code or not and disallow them to upload. I already checked mime type by **getimagesize()** but still unable to stop file having code that file includes **GIF89a1** to convert this file pretend as **mime type - gif**. How can I secure my code to check these kinds of files used by hackers. Please let me know.

Comment: By checking the MIME type you can prevent users from uploading other files...

Comment: As I said, already checked mime type it shows file is a gif but it has php code so the file is image with php code.